# Should I encrypt cookie name?

Tags: web, cookies

Recently I'm studying about cookie encryption.

There is a question I can't find a good enough answer.

Should I encrypt the cookie name?

I had searched a lot on Internet.

But there is a not a explained well information for me.

In my acknowledge, the purpose of cookie encryption is to secure the information in cookie.

Cookie value is obviously need to protect.

But what about Cookie name?

If anyone could provide more well-explain information, I'll be appreciated.

Thanks you!